# PHP 5.3 getallheaders

Tags: php, apache

I'm developing a web application for which it is required to capture custom header data sent by clients. In my localhost PHP 5.4 was installed and I'm using `getallheaders()`.

But in my hosting which has PHP 5.3 installed. I can't get the header. I already tried other ways such:

```
foreach ($_SERVER as $name => $value) 
{ 
    if (substr($name, 0, 5) == 'HTTP_') 
    {
        $name = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($name, 5))))); 
        $headers[$name] = $value; 
    } else if ($name == "CONTENT_TYPE") { 
        $headers["Content-Type"] = $value; 
    } else if ($name == "CONTENT_LENGTH") { 
        $headers["Content-Length"] = $value; 
    } 
}
```

and

```
apache_request_headers(), apache_response_headers()
```

Is there any other way? My hosting is using PHP 5.3 (FastCGI).

**UPDATE**

Well, i got where the problem came from. so first(for proofing the concept), i switch the PHP to run as Apache module, and yes as expected i able to use `getallheaders()`.

after that i tried other rest client/debuger to send custom header(now as FastCGI), and my code is able capture the header(inside $_SERVER). So the question is, why the first REST client able to send header only if the server run as Apache Module.

I'm afraid if one of my user got the same problem while the other is fine.

Comment: `getallheaders()` works in PHP 5.3 (and even PHP4).

Comment: do you have idea why it's not working for me ?

Comment: @JohnConde: `5.4.0  This function became available under FastCGI. Previously, it was supported only when PHP was installed as an Apache module.`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: What's the header you are looking for?  Maybe it doesn't start with `HTTP_`.

Comment: @John Conde : Yes you are right, but not for FastCGI. as i explain in my question that i'm running PHP as FastCGI

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat : It's custom header like 'foo', 'bar', 'key', etc. unfortunately i not find any custom header sent by request

Comment: Please read the Update